# correlated subquery and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I started learning Mysql, and I have a problem with understanding the **correlated subquery**, I've search for definitions saying, it executed once for each row, but when it comes to the examples:

```
DEPOT (N_Dpt, Name_Dpt, City)
STORE (N_Dpt #, N_Product #, Qt_Stored)
PRODUCT (N_Product, Label_Product, Price_U, Weight, Color)
```

List of highest unit prices for each product type

```
SELECT Product_Label, Price_U FROM Product AS P1  
WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX (Price_U) FROM PRODUCT P2  
WHERE P2. Product_Label = P1. Product Label )
```

**1st question** : why it is a correlated subquery?
**2nd question** : why can't we use GROUP BY ?

```
SELECT Product_label, MAX(Price_U) FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY Product_label
```

Comment: 1. It's correlated because p2.product_label equals p1.product_label. 2. You can use GROUP BY, but not within the context of a correlated subquery.

Comment: but how I would know that I have to use a correlated subquery, and by saying it's correlated because ''p2.....'' I didn't understand

Comment: You don't have to use a correlated subquery

Comment: Also, note that there is no 'price' column in your schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;

CREATE TABLE product
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,product_label CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,price_u INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
(1,'a',12),
(2,'a',18),
(3,'a',4),
(4,'b',9),
(5,'b',1),
(6,'c',13);


-- Correlated subquery:

SELECT product_label
     , price_u
  FROM product p1  
 WHERE price_u = (SELECT MAX(price_u) FROM product p2 WHERE p2.product_label = p1.product_label);
                                                      -----------------------------------------

 +---------------+---------+
 | product_label | price_u |
 +---------------+---------+
 | a             |      18 |
 | b             |       9 |
 | c             |      13 |
 +---------------+---------+
 
-- Uncorrelated subquery

SELECT x.product_label
     , x.price_u 
  FROM product x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT product_label
            , MAX(price_u) price_u
         FROM product 
        GROUP
           BY product_label
     ) y
    ON y.product_label = x.product_label
   AND y.price_u = x.price_u;

 +---------------+---------+
 | product_label | price_u |
 +---------------+---------+
 | a             |      18 |
 | b             |       9 |
 | c             |      13 |
 +---------------+---------+
   
-- No subquery

SELECT x.product_label
     , x.price_u 
  FROM product x
  LEFT
  JOIN product y
    ON y.product_label = x.product_label
   AND y.price_u > x.price_u
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;

 +---------------+---------+
 | product_label | price_u |
 +---------------+---------+
 | a             |      18 |
 | b             |       9 |
 | c             |      13 |
 +---------------+---------+
```

The above is not intended to be exhaustive

Comment: I used your code, but when I also my subquery above using GROUP BY "SELECT product_label, MAX(Price_u) FROM product GROUP BY product_label"  --> it gives the same result, so why did you use it with inner join?

Comment: Good point. It's in case I also wanted to return the other columns from the same row (id in this case, but there could be others)

Comment: Do you mean that we use correlated subquery when we want to return for each row (and it can be double) its result, Sorry but I am still confused when to use it

Comment: The three examples I've provided are all valid and can be used interchangeably (and there are others). The criteria for choosing one over the other comes down to performance; which one is quickest? This is related to the size of the data set, the indexes that are in place, and the cardinality (density/'sparsity') of the data. Your suggestion is also valid, but fails when we want to return additional columns because the values returned from those columns are 'indeterminate'; they don't necessarily correspond with the product_label and price_u values.